# Input do tipo text, com o mesmo comportamento de um input do tipo password

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jsf

Existe alguma maneira em Java Script onde eu possa ter um campo do tipo **text**, e ao digitar os caracteres eles serem transformados em *(Asterisco). E Depois conseguir recuperar esses valores para fazer algumas validações.

OBS: Não quero usar o tipo **password**, pois o browser sempre pergunta se deseja salvar esta senha.

Minha aplicação é em Java + JSF + PrimeFaces...

Exemplos:

Quero digitar esta senha no input do tipo password..

[image: Quero digitar esta senha no input do tipo password..]

Porem a medida que o usuario for digitando ele vai transformando os caracter digitados em asterisco tendo um resultado final assim:

[image: Resultado Final]

Obrigado !

Comment: Uma forma seria você criar mais um input do tipo hidden, que armazenaria o valor real digitado e capturar o evento keyup, keypress ou keydown deste campo atual e jogar o valor digitado para o hidden e depois substituir tudo por asterisco no input visível. Mas sinceramente, acho melhor deixar como tipo password e deixar o navegador perguntar se quer armazenar, não é culpa dos desenvolvedores esse comportamento.

Comment: Isso seria uma opção tbm, porém a resposta do @placementw me ajudou resolver o problema.

Muito obrigado pela dica também...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que alterar o tipo do caracter exibido no campo deve funcionar, testei em alguns browsers e deu certo, mas não tenho certeza se é uma solução 100% compatível

```html
<input type="text" name="password" style="text-security:disc; -webkit-text-security:disc;">
```

Edit: Importante você analisar se realmente precisa desse comportamento, os navegadores oferecem essa função por alguns bons motivos, um deles, por exemplo, é proporcionar ao usuário a "segurança" de poder utilizar senhas mais complexas que não vão precisar lembrar todas as vezes que forem acessar um serviço.

Comment: Isso msmo que estava precisando... O fato de não querer usar o type password, é porque tenho uma tela de fazer vendas, e utilizo este password quando o usuario deseja cancelar uma venda e seu acesso não permite...

O Problema que esta me causando ao usar o password, é que estava jogando valores aleatorios em outros campos que não tem nada haver com a senha.

Exemplo: o usuario digitava a senha e salvava no navegador, da proxima vez que ele entrar na tela o valor salvo era jogados em outros campos, tais como: Valor, qtde, Cliente entre outros. Não sei o porque deste comportamento.

Comment: Tranquilo! imaginei que fosse algo do tipo mas deixei o edit pra certificar que não ia ser usado de uma maneira a comprometer a segurança da tua aplicação : )